# Symfony Twig unable to create Select2 searchbar

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use Select2 multiple searchbar but i am not able to get it work. If i use this example: ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <!-- select2 -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- select2-bootstrap4-theme -->
    <link href="select2-bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h3>Example of <a href="https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme" target="_blank">@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme</a></h3>
      <hr>

      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Example select</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="select-single" placeholder="Choose one thing" data-allow-clear="1">
            <option></option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Example multiple select</label>
          <select multiple class="form-control" placeholder="Choose anything" data-allow-clear="1">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <!-- select2 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- select2-bootstrap4-theme -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it should be provided to the user
[image: This is how it should shown]

But instead of this it's showing this for me:

[image]

What am I missing in my html why it does not show the searchbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no detail about your **script.js** my proposal is:

```js
$('select').each(function(idx, ele) {
    $(ele).select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        placeholder: ele.getAttribute('placeholder')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- select2 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@master/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container mt-5">
    <h3>Example of <a href="https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme" target="_blank">@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme</a></h3>
    <hr>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Example select</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="select-single" placeholder="Choose one thing" data-allow-clear="1">
                <option></option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Example multiple select</label>
            <select multiple class="form-control" placeholder="Choose anything" data-allow-clear="1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.